# An error in BigQuery when trying to combine conditions to one string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

so i have a channel_name field and i want to check if channel_name is "X" OR a field in a subquery is not null then return "X" else return channel_name

i tried this:

```
(CASE WHEN channel_name = "X" or (select travel.trip360_id from `gcommerce-analytics-prod.test.PRE_ANALYSIS_temp` as snap 
left join `grouponi_groupon.tb_travel_opportunities`  as travel on snap.order_item_opportunity_id = travel.opportunity_id)
 is not null then "X" else channel_name end) as channel_name
```

but i get the error: "Scalar subquery produced more than one element"

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

It is the subquery embeded into your case expression, it can return multiple rows. This is not allowed within a select clause, so you need to modify that subquery so it can only return a single value e.g. by using the `MAX()` function:

```
(
    CASE 
        WHEN channel_name = "X"
            OR (
                SELECT MAX(travel.trip360_id)
                FROM `gcommerce - analytics - prod.test.PRE_ANALYSIS_temp` AS snap
                LEFT JOIN `grouponi_groupon.tb_travel_opportunities` AS travel
                    ON snap.order_item_opportunity_id = travel.opportunity_id
                ) IS NOT NULL
            THEN "X"
        ELSE channel_name
        END
    ) AS channel_name
```

if that isn't workable, perhaps using EXISTS will e.g:

```
(
    CASE 
        WHEN channel_name = "X"
        OR EXISTS (
                SELECT MAX(1)
                FROM `gcommerce - analytics - prod.test.PRE_ANALYSIS_temp` AS snap
                LEFT JOIN `grouponi_groupon.tb_travel_opportunities` AS travel
                    ON snap.order_item_opportunity_id = travel.opportunity_id
                ) 
            THEN "X"
        ELSE channel_name
        END
    ) AS channel_name
```